# How to create CMYK halftone Images from a color image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, cmyk

I am working on a project that requires me to separate out each color in a CYMK image and generate a halftone image that will be printed on a special halftone printer. The method used is analogues to silk screening in that the process is almost identical. Take a photo and break out each color channel. Then produce a screen for the half tone. Each color screen must have it's screen skewed by 15-45 (adjustable) degrees. Dot size and LPI must be calculated from user configurable values to achieve different effects. This process I am told is used in silk screening but I have been unable to locate any information that explains CYMK halftoning. I find plenty for reducing to a single color and generating new print style b/w halftone image.

I would guess that I need to:

1. split the file into it's color channels.
2. generate a monochrome halftone image for that channel.
3. Skew the resultant halftone image by the number of degrees * channel number.

Does anyone know if this is the correct approach and any existing python code for this? Or of any good explanations for this process or algorithms?

Comment: updated my code, hope its helpful ;)

Comment: Now linked: [How to halftone a black and white picture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828014/how-to-halftone-a-black-and-white-picture)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I used to run a screen printing studio (it was a fairly small one), and although I have never actually done colour separation printing, I am reasonably familiar with the principles. This is how I would approach it:

1. Split the image into C, M, Y, K.
2. Rotate each separated image by 0, 15, 30, and 45 degrees respectively.
3. Take the half-tone of each image (dot size will be proportional to the intensity).
4. Rotate back each half-toned image.

Now you have your colour separated images. As you mention, the rotation step reduces dot alignment issues (which would mess everything up), and things like [Moiré pattern effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) will be reasonably minimized.

This should be pretty easy to code using [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm).

**Update 2:**

I wrote some quick code that will do this for you, it also includes a `GCR` function (described below):

```
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageStat

def gcr(im, percentage):
    '''basic "Gray Component Replacement" function. Returns a CMYK image with 
       percentage gray component removed from the CMY channels and put in the
       K channel, ie. for percentage=100, (41, 100, 255, 0) >> (0, 59, 214, 41)'''
    cmyk_im = im.convert('CMYK')
    if not percentage:
        return cmyk_im
    cmyk_im = cmyk_im.split()
    cmyk = []
    for i in xrange(4):
        cmyk.append(cmyk_im[i].load())
    for x in xrange(im.size[0]):
        for y in xrange(im.size[1]):
            gray = min(cmyk[0][x,y], cmyk[1][x,y], cmyk[2][x,y]) * percentage / 100
            for i in xrange(3):
                cmyk[i][x,y] = cmyk[i][x,y] - gray
            cmyk[3][x,y] = gray
    return Image.merge('CMYK', cmyk_im)

def halftone(im, cmyk, sample, scale):
    '''Returns list of half-tone images for cmyk image. sample (pixels), 
       determines the sample box size from the original image. The maximum 
       output dot diameter is given by sample * scale (which is also the number 
       of possible dot sizes). So sample=1 will presevere the original image 
       resolution, but scale must be >1 to allow variation in dot size.'''
    cmyk = cmyk.split()
    dots = []
    angle = 0
    for channel in cmyk:
        channel = channel.rotate(angle, expand=1)
        size = channel.size[0]*scale, channel.size[1]*scale
        half_tone = Image.new('L', size)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(half_tone)
        for x in xrange(0, channel.size[0], sample):
            for y in xrange(0, channel.size[1], sample):
                box = channel.crop((x, y, x + sample, y + sample))
                stat = ImageStat.Stat(box)
                diameter = (stat.mean[0] / 255)**0.5
                edge = 0.5*(1-diameter)
                x_pos, y_pos = (x+edge)*scale, (y+edge)*scale
                box_edge = sample*diameter*scale
                draw.ellipse((x_pos, y_pos, x_pos + box_edge, y_pos + box_edge), fill=255)
        half_tone = half_tone.rotate(-angle, expand=1)
        width_half, height_half = half_tone.size
        xx=(width_half-im.size[0]*scale) / 2
        yy=(height_half-im.size[1]*scale) / 2
        half_tone = half_tone.crop((xx, yy, xx + im.size[0]*scale, yy + im.size[1]*scale))
        dots.append(half_tone)
        angle += 15
    return dots

im = Image.open("1_tree.jpg")

cmyk = gcr(im, 0)
dots = halftone(im, cmyk, 10, 1)
im.show()
new = Image.merge('CMYK', dots)
new.show()
```

This will turn this:

[image]

into this (blur your eyes and move away from the monitor):

[image]

Note that the image sampling can be pixel by pixel (thus preserving the resolution of the original image, in the final image). Do this by setting `sample=1`, in which case you need to set `scale` to a larger number so that there are a number of possible dot sizes. This will also result in a larger output image size (original image size * scale ** 2, so watch out!).

By default when you convert from `RGB` to `CMYK` the `K` channel (the black channel) is empty. Whether you need the `K` channel or not depends upon your printing process. There are various possible reasons you might want it: getting a better black than the overlap of `CMY`, saving ink, improving drying time, reducing ink bleed, etc. Anyhow I've also written a little [Grey component replacement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_component_replacement) function `GCR`, so you can set the percentage of `K` channel you want to replace `CMY` overlap with (I explain this a little further in the code comments).

Here is a couple of examples to illustrate. Processing the `letter F` from the image, with `sample=1` and `scale=8`, so fairly high resolution.

The 4 `CMYK` channels, with `percentage=0`, so empty `K` channel:

[image][image][image][image]

combines to produce:

[image]

`CMYK` channels, with `percentage=100`, so `K` channel is used. You can see the cyan channel is fully supressed, and the magenta and yellow channels use a lot less ink, in the black band at the bottom of the image:

[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: @user69333 - Cool, good luck with that! By the way I'm fraxel (different from Andrew, who also answered..). I would appreciate it if you could 'accept my answer', by clicking the tick, its the way that stackoverflow works (we both get points... whoop), cheers.

Comment: Thanks again Andrew. Your grey scale component may come in handy. Most of what I've learned here has come from T-Shirt sites. Now it's got me thinking about doing some OSS for t-shirt printing. However, I noticed that the commercial software seems to use the RGB as well as the CMYK channels and other screens as well. I read a tut on using Photoshop for screen printing t-shirts and it seems their is a lot to it. As for my printer project you got me off to a very good start. I'm going to add your grey scale code and make a few more mods.

Comment: I played around with some angles I found on the net ranging from 10 degrees to 60 degrees per channel and found that some combinations result in really bad moire pattern effects while others reduce these effects. My code allows me to set specific angles for each channel so I can use angles that are not incremental. This seems to help reduce the effects but can also change the the perceived color. It's kind of cool to mess around with ;-)

Comment: Sorry about the name mix up. Still not sure just how this site works.

Comment: @user69333 - If you could accept my answer, that would be great! (you've currently accepted andrews answer...). I also found this site very confusing at first!

Comment: hah.  i just tried to delete my answer in case that would help, but once it's marked best i can't delete it...

Comment: @andrew cook - ha, and cheers ;) hopefully user69333 will figure it out. Anyhows, I had a bunch of fun playing with all that stuff, and thats the main thing!

Comment: @fraxel - OK, I hope clicking the check mark on this thread accepts your answer? I just played a few minutes with your code. Cool stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @user693336 - yeah, its sorted now! nice one, and Enjoy!

Comment: In case it's useful to anyone else, I put @fraxel's code into a python module (as best as my limited knowledge allows), and made it easier to tweak the angles of the CMYK: https://github.com/philgyford/python-halftone

Answer (score 6):

My solution also uses PIL, but relies on the internal dithering method (Floyd-Steinberg) supported internally. Creates artifacts, though, so I am considering rewriting its C code.

```
    from PIL import Image

    im  = Image.open('tree.jpg')             # open RGB image
    cmyk= im.convert('CMYK').split()         # RGB contone RGB to CMYK contone
    c = cmyk[0].convert('1').convert('L')    # and then halftone ('1') each plane
    m = cmyk[1].convert('1').convert('L')    # ...and back to ('L') mode
    y = cmyk[2].convert('1').convert('L')
    k = cmyk[3].convert('1').convert('L')

    new_cmyk = Image.merge('CMYK',[c,m,y,k]) # put together all 4 planes
    new_cmyk.save('tree-cmyk.jpg')           # and save to file
```

The implicit GCR PIL applies can also be expanded with a more generic one, but I have tried to describe a simple solution, where also resolution and sampling are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

With ordered (Bayer) Dither using D4 pattern, we can modify @fraxel's code to end up with an output dithered image with 4 times the height and width of the input color image, as shown below

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def ordered_dither(im, D4):
    im = (15 * (im / im.max())).astype(np.uint8)
    h, w = im.shape
    im_out = np.zeros((4 * h, 4 * w), dtype = np.uint8)
    x, y = 0, 0
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            im_out[x:x + 4, y:y + 4] = 255 * (D4 < im[i, j])
            y = (y + 4) % (4 * w)
        x = (x + 4) % (4 * h)
    return im_out

def color_halftoning_Bayer(cmyk, angles, D4):
    out_channels = []    
    for i in range(4):
        out_channel = Image.fromarray(
                            ordered_dither(np.asarray(cmyk[i].rotate(angles[i],expand=1)), D4)
                      ).rotate(-angles[i], expand=1)
        x = (out_channel.size[0] - cmyk[i].size[0]*4) // 2
        y = (out_channel.size[1] - cmyk[i].size[1]*4) // 2
        out_channel = out_channel.crop((x, y, x + cmyk[i].size[0]*4, y + cmyk[i].size[1]*4))
        out_channels.append(out_channel)
    return Image.merge('CMYK',out_channels)

image = Image.open('images/tree.jpg')
cmyk = gcr(image,100).split()   
D4 = np.array([[ 0,  8,  2, 10],
               [12,  4, 14,  6],
               [ 3, 11,  1,  9],
               [15,  7, 13,  5]], dtype=np.uint8)

out = np.asarray(color_halftoning_Bayer(cmyk, np.linspace(15, 60, 4), D4).convert('RGB'))
plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
plt.imshow(out)
plt.show()
```

The above code when ran on the following tree input

[image]

it generates the following dithered output:

[image]

Comment: What does the gcr() function do? I don't understand where it comes from.