# Image to grid hole pattern on Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to know how to convert (using Python) an image into a hole-pattern grid image, like this:

I want to generate a resulting image like the one as shown there in the preview made with holes - filled circles.

[image: https://www.cadstudio.cz/img/ext/boreimage1.png]

Comment: Downscale your grayscale image to 32x32. Then, draw circles on a new image corresponding for each pixel in your downsized one. Set each circle's radius according to the value of the pixel in the downsized image.

Answer (score 2):

This is a referred to as Halftone (dotted) i think. Here's a related Thread which talks about image processing:
[Halftone Images In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572274/halftone-images-in-python/10575940#10575940)

Seems like somebody already wrote something in python referring to that linked thread here is the git:
https://github.com/philgyford/python-halftone

Comment: Thanks, I will find it with that definition then.

Comment: It worked just great, now I'm trying to center the dots, I asked for help at that same post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48609766/439381 . Thanks.