# Halftone using different radius circle on white background using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry, python-imaging-library

I am trying to add effect to my images using halftone concept
I have already tried white halftones circle on black background (thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575940/5003003))
but i actually wanted this type of effect [by Morgan henty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgvCpiJRb3g) 
Can someone help me how to get the radius of black circle for that block of pixels & that double masking of 2 images using halftone too

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For grayscale image circle radius should be proportional to square root of reversed brightness (if we ignore oversize effects)

```
R = Coeff * CellSize * Sqrt((255 - Brightness)/255)  
//or Sqrt(1.0- Brightness)  for 0..1 range
//Coeff = 1/2 gives 2R=CellSize for dark with fill degree about 0.76
```